# Assign delegate in If/else vs ?:

Tags: c#

Why is this code compiling:

```
Func<BeExp, IEnumerable<BeExp>> collectFunc;
if (lhs.Kind == BExpKind.BESum)
{
    collectFunc = CollectSumTerms;
}
else
{
    collectFunc = CollectProdTerms;
}
```

whereas this is not?

```
Func<BeExp, IEnumerable<BeExp>> collectFunc = lhs.Kind == BExpKind.BESum ? CollectSumTerms : CollectProdTerms;
```

Error:

> Error CS0173  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'method group' and 'method group'

Comment: I think it is because when you use the operator ":",  the left side (when the clause is true) and right (when it's false) has to have the same type .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide an exact signature to the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) for at least one method in the group.

```
var collectFunc = lhs.Kind == BExpKind.BESum ? (Func<BeExp, IEnumerable<BeExp>>)CollectSumTerms : CollectProdTerms;
```